# why is my array.length not increasing?

Tags: javascript, arrays, increment

Doesn't the addition of an array element by push increase the length of the array by 1 ?

```
var parameters = [];
if (parameters.length == 0) {
    // join select menu and option then add to parameters array
    var parameterSelected = nameOfSelectBox + " " + ":" + " " + $i + ",";
    parameters.push(parameterSelected);
} else {
    var parameterSelected = "," + " " + nameOfSelectBox + " " + ":" + " " + $i;
    parameters.push(parameterSelected);
}
// check for repeats
// does a select input exist?
// add to appropriate indexes then add new or modify existing parameters
console.log(parameters.length);
});
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly.

Comment: What's this here for `});`?

Comment: parameters array will always be zero. there's no push on it before you validate it.

Comment: @AndréPedroso surely the push in the else clause gets executed, so the length should be 1

Comment: @NickSlash you're right. Just saying BEFORE validation (if clause) the array will be always Zero.

Comment: realized i misunderstood your comment after i posted :( ignore me

Comment: this isn't the entire code like $i is the selected option, this is part of another function. I'm responding to the comment of what }); is for

Comment: Side note: If the strings in the array are eventually combined into a single string, you shouldn't need to manage the separator yourself with an `if..else`. Using [`parameters.join(', ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) will already do that for you.

Comment: What are you expecting? This code does increased the length by 1, the length is `1` after this ran. The array is empty at the start so the length is `0` then incremented to `1`.

Comment: Once at least one entry exists, I have to check if the next entry is the same one so that it can be replaced. This search engine I'm building outputs the selected options in a text input and if someone changes their mind on a parameter, the parameter should not be re-added to the text input field rather replaced. I'm just stuck on this array thing, I've only recently began to use them in javascript. Thanks for all of the responses, I imagine it won't be long now before I am blocked again for like the sixth time jesus christ

Comment: Forget the arrays for now I'm just going to use concatenated strings, I'm literally just keeping track of what options were selected and if I know how to solve that problem with something that I am familiar with eg. string concatenation and str.match() then why waste my time with arrays. It's not a waste, I'd like to use them in the future and I more than likely have to but I'd rather use php but I realize client and server side applications. Thanks for everyone's input.

Answer (score 3):

In your current code it will never go to else because

```
var parameters = [];
```

always sets its length to 0 because you just declare `parameters` again. Then you add one element to the array and its length changes to 1 and that is it.

Answer (score 0):

you should do something like this:

```
   var my_array = []; // zero

   my_array.push("abc"); // one

   my_array.push("def"); // two
```

Comment: I tried this and it did not work. I'm not saying your answer is incorrect, there is more than likely something wrong on my end.

Comment: dude... i cant help you any more... if the above code doesnt work I dont know how to help you...